# python corrupted double-linked list error

Tags: python, ubuntu

i am a python 2.7 and ubuntu 16.04 user and i have unexpected error when try to excute some python scripts .
i use pycharm and i have the some error when i try to run python script from the ubuntu terminal.
the error :

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python2.7': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0b83c880 ***
```

the error  message :

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xb764b377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xb76512f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6e2f1)[0xb76522f1]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x18)[0xb6ba9d88]
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.1(_ZN15GDALMajorObjectD0Ev+0x22)[0xb075a582]
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.1(GDALClose+0x77)[0xb074d747]
/usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgdalprovider.so(+0xa930)[0xa4888930]
/usr/lib/qgis/plugins/libgdalprovider.so(+0xaafa)[0xa4888afa]
/usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.18.3(_ZN13QgsRasterPipeD1Ev+0x75)[0xb3d6a7d5]
/usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.18.3(_ZN14QgsRasterLayerD1Ev+0x2f)[0xb3d5cd0f]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/_core.i386-linux-gnu.so(_ZN17sipQgsRasterLayerD1Ev+0x3b)[0xb489dd2b]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/_core.i386-linux-gnu.so(_ZN17sipQgsRasterLayerD0Ev+0x1a)[0xb489dd5a]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/_core.i386-linux-gnu.so(+0x43df45)[0xb4883f45]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/_core.i386-linux-gnu.so(+0x43df8a)[0xb4883f8a]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.i386-linux-gnu.so(+0x5d49)[0xb724dd49]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.i386-linux-gnu.so(+0xc19b)[0xb725419b]
/usr/bin/python2.7[0x8144aad]
/usr/bin/python2.7[0x80fd127]
/usr/bin/python2.7(PyDict_SetItem+0x478)[0x80e9268]
/usr/bin/python2.7(_PyModule_Clear+0xba)[0x8149a1a]
/usr/bin/python2.7(PyImport_Cleanup+0x37a)[0x81495ca]
/usr/bin/python2.7(Py_Finalize+0x99)[0x8147399]
/usr/bin/python2.7(Py_Main+0x4bd)[0x80e639d]
/usr/bin/python2.7(main+0x26)[0x80e5ec6]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xb75fc637]
/usr/bin/python2.7[0x80e5dc8]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0838f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1583892    /usr/bin/python2.7
08390000-08391000 r--p 00347000 08:01 1583892    /usr/bin/python2.7
08391000-083f1000 rw-p 00348000 08:01 1583892    /usr/bin/python2.7
083f1000-08406000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0a0f7000-0ba69000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
a03e0000-a03eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1049930    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
a03eb000-a03ec000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 1049930    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
a03ec000-a03ed000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 1049930    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
a03ed000-a03f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a03f3000-a03fe000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1048664    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
a03fe000-a03ff000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 1048664    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
a03ff000-a0400000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 1048664    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
a0400000-a0421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a0421000-a0500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
a0509000-a0520000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1048674    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
a0520000-a0521000 r--p 00016000 08:01 1048674    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
a0521000-a0522000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 1048674    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
a0522000-a0524000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a0524000-a052c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1048675    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
a052c000-a052d000 r--p 00007000 08:01 1048675    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
a052d000-a052e000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 1048675    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
a054a000-a054b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
a054b000-a10cb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a10cb000-a10d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 150141     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so
a10d4000-a10d5000 r--p 00008000 08:01 150141     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so
a10d5000-a10d6000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 150141     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so
a10d6000-a1296000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1296000-a12a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 283552     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/mvn.i386-linux-gnu.so
a12a5000-a12a6000 ---p 0000f000 08:01 283552     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/mvn.i386-linux-gnu.so
a12a6000-a12a7000 r--p 0000f000 08:01 283552     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/mvn.i386-linux-gnu.so
a12a7000-a12a8000 rw-p 00010000 08:01 283552     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/mvn.i386-linux-gnu.so
a12a8000-a139f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a139f000-a13a8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 283553     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/statlib.i386-linux-gnu.so
a13a8000-a13a9000 ---p 00009000 08:01 283553     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/statlib.i386-linux-gnu.so
a13a9000-a13aa000 r--p 00009000 08:01 283553     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/statlib.i386-linux-gnu.so
a13aa000-a13ab000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 283553     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/statlib.i386-linux-gnu.so
a13ab000-a13eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a13eb000-a13f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 283548     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_rank.i386-linux-gnu.so
a13f8000-a13f9000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 283548     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_rank.i386-linux-gnu.so
a13f9000-a13fb000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 283548     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_rank.i386-linux-gnu.so
a13fb000-a147b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a147b000-a148e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 283509     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/vonmises_cython.i386-linux-gnu.so
a148e000-a148f000 r--p 00012000 08:01 283509     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/vonmises_cython.i386-linux-gnu.so
a148f000-a1490000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 283509     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/vonmises_cython.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1490000-a1510000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1510000-a1519000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534502     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_nnls.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1519000-a151a000 r--p 00008000 08:01 534502     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_nnls.i386-linux-gnu.so
a151a000-a151b000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 534502     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_nnls.i386-linux-gnu.so
a151b000-a1539000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534537     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1539000-a153a000 r--p 0001d000 08:01 534537     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.i386-linux-gnu.so
a153a000-a153c000 rw-p 0001e000 08:01 534537     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.i386-linux-gnu.so
a153c000-a1562000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534554     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_group_columns.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1562000-a1563000 r--p 00025000 08:01 534554     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_group_columns.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1563000-a1565000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 534554     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_group_columns.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1565000-a157b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534540     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a157b000-a157c000 r--p 00015000 08:01 534540     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a157c000-a157d000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 534540     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a157d000-a1592000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534543     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_slsqp.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1592000-a1593000 r--p 00014000 08:01 534543     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_slsqp.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1593000-a1594000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 534543     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_slsqp.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1594000-a15ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534495     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_cobyla.i386-linux-gnu.so
a15ad000-a15ae000 r--p 00018000 08:01 534495     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_cobyla.i386-linux-gnu.so
a15ae000-a15af000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 534495     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_cobyla.i386-linux-gnu.so
a15af000-a15b7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534499     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/moduleTNC.i386-linux-gnu.so
a15b7000-a15b8000 r--p 00007000 08:01 534499     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/moduleTNC.i386-linux-gnu.so
a15b8000-a15b9000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 534499     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/moduleTNC.i386-linux-gnu.so
a15b9000-a15f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a15f9000-a1689000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 412052     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/_arpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1689000-a168a000 r--p 0008f000 08:01 412052     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/_arpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a168a000-a1692000 rw-p 00090000 08:01 412052     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/_arpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1692000-a16e9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 412020     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlu.i386-linux-gnu.so
a16e9000-a16ea000 r--p 00056000 08:01 412020     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlu.i386-linux-gnu.so
a16ea000-a16eb000 rw-p 00057000 08:01 412020     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlu.i386-linux-gnu.so
a16eb000-a171f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 412028     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.i386-linux-gnu.so
a171f000-a1720000 r--p 00033000 08:01 412028     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1720000-a1726000 rw-p 00034000 08:01 412028     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1726000-a1727000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1727000-a1766000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 412005     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1766000-a1767000 ---p 0003f000 08:01 412005     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1767000-a1768000 r--p 0003f000 08:01 412005     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1768000-a176c000 rw-p 00040000 08:01 412005     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.i386-linux-gnu.so
a176c000-a1790000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 412007     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1790000-a1791000 r--p 00023000 08:01 412007     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1791000-a1794000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 412007     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1794000-a1795000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1795000-a17b4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 411990     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.i386-linux-gnu.so
a17b4000-a17b5000 r--p 0001e000 08:01 411990     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.i386-linux-gnu.so
a17b5000-a17ba000 rw-p 0001f000 08:01 411990     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.i386-linux-gnu.so
a17ba000-a17d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 411992     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a17d9000-a17da000 r--p 0001e000 08:01 411992     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a17da000-a17de000 rw-p 0001f000 08:01 411992     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a17de000-a1812000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 412004     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1812000-a1813000 r--p 00033000 08:01 412004     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1813000-a1818000 rw-p 00034000 08:01 412004     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1818000-a1858000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1858000-a18b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 283597     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a18b3000-a18b4000 r--p 0005a000 08:01 283597     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a18b4000-a18b8000 rw-p 0005b000 08:01 283597     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a18b8000-a1bcd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 283577     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1bcd000-a1bce000 r--p 00314000 08:01 283577     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1bce000-a1bcf000 rw-p 00315000 08:01 283577     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1bcf000-a1beb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534539     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lbfgsb.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1beb000-a1bec000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 534539     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lbfgsb.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1bec000-a1bed000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 534539     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lbfgsb.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1bed000-a1c2d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1c2d000-a1c36000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534548     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack2.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c36000-a1c37000 r--p 00008000 08:01 534548     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack2.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c37000-a1c38000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 534548     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack2.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c38000-a1c5d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534392     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/lsoda.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c5d000-a1c5e000 r--p 00024000 08:01 534392     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/lsoda.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c5e000-a1c5f000 rw-p 00025000 08:01 534392     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/lsoda.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c5f000-a1c60000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1c60000-a1c75000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534374     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_dop.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c75000-a1c76000 r--p 00014000 08:01 534374     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_dop.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c76000-a1c78000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 534374     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_dop.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1c78000-a1ca3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534376     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/vode.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1ca3000-a1ca4000 r--p 0002a000 08:01 534376     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/vode.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1ca4000-a1ca5000 rw-p 0002b000 08:01 534376     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/vode.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1ca5000-a1ce6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1ce6000-a1d00000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534375     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d00000-a1d01000 r--p 00019000 08:01 534375     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d01000-a1d02000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 534375     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d02000-a1d23000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 534393     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_odepack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d23000-a1d24000 r--p 00020000 08:01 534393     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_odepack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d24000-a1d25000 rw-p 00021000 08:01 534393     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_odepack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d25000-a1d36000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701893     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d36000-a1d37000 r--p 00010000 08:01 701893     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d37000-a1d38000 rw-p 00011000 08:01 701893     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1d38000-a1dd4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701842     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1dd4000-a1dd5000 r--p 0009b000 08:01 701842     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1dd5000-a1dda000 rw-p 0009c000 08:01 701842     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1dda000-a1e0f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701852     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/cython_blas.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e0f000-a1e10000 r--p 00034000 08:01 701852     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/cython_blas.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e10000-a1e13000 rw-p 00035000 08:01 701852     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/cython_blas.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e13000-a1e5d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701797     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e5d000-a1e5e000 r--p 00049000 08:01 701797     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e5e000-a1e67000 rw-p 0004a000 08:01 701797     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e67000-a1e97000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701803     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e97000-a1e98000 r--p 0002f000 08:01 701803     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e98000-a1e9b000 rw-p 00030000 08:01 701803     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1e9b000-a1edb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a1edb000-a1ee8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701813     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_flinalg.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1ee8000-a1ee9000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 701813     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_flinalg.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1ee9000-a1eeb000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 701813     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_flinalg.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1eeb000-a1f92000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701847     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_flapack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1f92000-a1f93000 r--p 000a6000 08:01 701847     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_flapack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1f93000-a1fc1000 rw-p 000a7000 08:01 701847     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_flapack.i386-linux-gnu.so
a1fc1000-a200a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701814     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.i386-linux-gnu.so
a200a000-a200b000 r--p 00048000 08:01 701814     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.i386-linux-gnu.so
a200b000-a201f000 rw-p 00049000 08:01 701814     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.i386-linux-gnu.so
a201f000-a20b6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701913     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/specfun.i386-linux-gnu.so
a20b6000-a20b7000 r--p 00096000 08:01 701913     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/specfun.i386-linux-gnu.so
a20b7000-a20bc000 rw-p 00097000 08:01 701913     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/specfun.i386-linux-gnu.so
a20bc000-a20d0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701917     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.i386-linux-gnu.so
a20d0000-a20d1000 r--p 00013000 08:01 701917     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.i386-linux-gnu.so
a20d1000-a20d2000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 701917     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.i386-linux-gnu.so
a20d2000-a21ea000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 701916     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.i386-linux-gnu.so
a21ea000-a21eb000 ---p 00118000 08:01 701916     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.i386-linux-gnu.so
a21eb000-a21ec000 r--p 00118000 08:01 701916     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.i386-linux-gnu.so
a21ec000-a21ff000 rw-p 00119000 08:01 701916     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.i386-linux-gnu.so
a21ff000-a22c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a22c2000-a2307000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 147207     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_agg.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2307000-a2308000 r--p 00044000 08:01 147207     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_agg.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2308000-a2309000 rw-p 00045000 08:01 147207     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_agg.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2309000-a23ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a23ca000-a242b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 147376     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_qhull.i386-linux-gnu.so
a242b000-a242c000 r--p 00060000 08:01 147376     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_qhull.i386-linux-gnu.so
a242c000-a242d000 rw-p 00061000 08:01 147376     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_qhull.i386-linux-gnu.so
a242d000-a242e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a242e000-a2447000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 147399     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_tri.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2447000-a2448000 r--p 00018000 08:01 147399     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_tri.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2448000-a2449000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 147399     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_tri.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2449000-a2509000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a2509000-a252f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 147142     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_image.i386-linux-gnu.so
a252f000-a2530000 r--p 00025000 08:01 147142     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_image.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2530000-a2531000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 147142     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_image.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2531000-a25b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a25b2000-a25bf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 147249     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_contour.i386-linux-gnu.so
a25bf000-a25c0000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 147249     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_contour.i386-linux-gnu.so
a25c0000-a25c1000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 147249     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/_contour.i386-linux-gnu.so
a25c1000-a260c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 146816     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.i386-linux-gnu.so
a260c000-a260e000 r--p 0004a000 08:01 146816     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.i386-linux-gnu.so
a260e000-a2610000 rw-p 0004c000 08:01 146816     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/_imaging.i386-linux-gnu.so
a2610000-a2690000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
a2690000-a26a1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 147230     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.i386-linux-gnu.so
a26a1000-a26a2000 ---p 00011000 08:01 147230     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
bf8e6000-bf907000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, the error also comes from your IDE? Can you trace back some of the last lines executed in the script which are ran before the error occurs?

Comment: looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134948/python-select-select-select-poll-corrupted-double-linked-list, and https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/273160/what-is-this-huge-wxpython-error

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi that error i have and when i try to uses frm terminal

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar issue when running an web application in uwsgi + django, which was to upload files to an external FTP server.

after digging into the repo steps, I found that this issue only happened in threading context, this is my uwsgi threads line:

> threads = 2

after commenting out this line, it was fixed.